# Why does the command promt respond differently to mysql -v and mysql --version?

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line

When I type in command prompt:

```
mysql -v
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

But when I type

```
MySQL --version
```

I get:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.32 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Is there a reason for this? "-v" works with other things like "node -v" and "npm -v", it's just MySQL that has a problem.

I am trying to set up my environment to begin a project with JS, does this issue seem like something that will affect the development of my project?

Comment: What makes you think that `-v` is the universal code to get _"version"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-v` flag to the MySQL client is not short for `--version`. You can see this if you run `mysql --help`:

```
...
  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
  -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
...
```

If you use `-v`, it tries the default action, which is to connect to the local MySQL instance, and verbose output will be produced during your session. Since you didn't specify a username, it defaults (on Windows) to `ODBC@localhost`. You apparently haven't created this user, or else the user requires a password. That's why you get Access Denied when you specify the user but no password.

If you use `-V` or `--version`, it skips trying to connect, and only prints the version of the client.